# fmod function returning wrong result

Tags: php, floating-point

I'm getting fmod returning wrong result, am i doing anything wrong?

```
for($i = 0.00; $i < 1; $i = $i + 0.05) {
    var_dump($i." = ".fmod($i, 0.05));
}
```

Output:

```
0.= 0
0.05 = 0
0.1 = 0
0.15 = 1.3877787807814E-17
0.2 = 0
0.25 = 0.05
0.3 = 0.05
0.35 = 0.05
0.4 = 0.05
0.45 = 0.05
0.5 = 0.05
0.55 = 0.05
0.6 = 0.05
0.65 = 0.05
0.7 = 2.7755575615629E-17
0.75 = 6.9388939039072E-17
0.8 = 1.1102230246252E-16
0.85 = 1.5265566588596E-16
0.9 = 1.942890293094E-16
0.95 = 2.3592239273285E-16
```

I was expecting every result to be the same: 0.

Comment: What do you expect the result to be?

Comment: You might want to take a look at the docs

Comment: i mistook in the code i showed, it's updated now.

Comment: The answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/3933332 (Also add this line in your loop: `echo sprintf("%.20f", $i);` and you will see it)

Comment: The operands shown above are not exactly respresentable as binary floating-point numbers. `fmod()` always delivers an exact result based on the actual value stored in the double-precision floating-point source operands.

Comment: @Sheraf Is your question now answered or where are we?

Answer (score 1):

First, `fmod` is exact. Because it can: when `x` and `y` are floating-point numbers, the mathematical result of `fmod(x,y)` can be represented exactly as a floating-point number.

Second, when you write `0.05`, you do not get exactly that number, because 5/100 on the other hand cannot be represented exactly as a floating-point number; and when you write `+`, you do not get mathematical addition in general because the result of that mathematical addition cannot always be represented as a floating-point number(*).

Starting from 0.0 and repeatedly adding 0.05 will soon get you into inaccurate `+` territory, because in binary, the best representation of 0.05 has many digits. As the sum gets larger, the last digits progressively have to be dropped. This is where the inaccuracy of `+` comes from, and ultimately is the reason why `fmod` does not give you the results you expect.

It wouldn't matter that `0.05` is not exactly 5/100 if repeatedly adding it to zero always was exact. But since the floating-point number `0.05` has many digits in binary (as opposed to decimal) and since some of these digits must be lost when computing multiples of `0.05`, the value you get for most multiples `y` of `0.05` when computing `fmod(y, 0.05)` is not zero but represents the difference between the mathematical multiplication of the appropriate integer by `0.05` and the approximation `y` of that number.

(*) when the mathematical sum can be represented, the mathematical sum is what you get, but sometimes it just cannot.

Answer (score 0):

#### This answer relates to the first revision of the question:

https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/28372286/1

All is working fine! You can calculate it for yourself:

```
fmod(0.5, 0.25);
fmod(0.5, 0.23);
fmod(0.5, 0.20);
```

```
0.25 * 2 = 0.50   | Rest 0.00
0.23 * 2 = 0.46   | Rest 0.04
0.20 * 2 = 0.40   | Rest 0.10
```