# Getting the modulo of two real numbers with BCMath

Tags: php, bcmath

I would like to find out whether one real number is a multitude of the other one. I'm using BC-Math because the code is part of a larger system doing price calculations and using floats results in wrong results on multiple calculations due to the behaviour of floating point math.

BC-Math has `bcmod()` to get the modulus of an arbitrary precision number. However, before PHP 7.2 this function does not work with non-integer numeric strings. E.g:

```
echo bcmod('10', '9.2'); // 1, because '9.2' is truncated to '9'
```

Converting the numbers back to floats and using `fmod()` isn't an option since [fmod function returning wrong result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28372286/fmod-function-returning-wrong-result)

I couldn't find any solution to this problem but I can't image that there is no solution.

**EDIT:**

Hello reader in the future who encounters the same problem! Based on @chiliNUT's response I created a [pull-request](https://github.com/krowinski/bcmath-extended/pull/13) for the [bcmath-extended](https://github.com/krowinski/bcmath-extended) library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it can be done using some math:

You can relate `mod(a,b)` to `a` and `b` with this equation:

```
a = b * floor(a/b) + mod(a,b)
```

([explanation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10%20mod%209.2))

and then solve that equation for mod to yield

```
mod(a,b) = a - b * floor(a/b)
```

Substituting your numbers you get

```
mod(10,9.2) = 10 - 9.2 * floor(10/9.2) = 0.8
```

Also see here for a bcmath floor implementation: [How to ceil, floor and round bcmath numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642614/how-to-ceil-floor-and-round-bcmath-numbers)

Comment: I love your approach! Your calculation however has an error. ``mod(a,b) = a - b * floor(a/b)`` instead of ``mod(a,b) = a/b - b * floor(a/b)``. Will you correct your answer so I can accept?